# How to close all MacOS windows before sleep

Tags: windows, macos

The answer to this question is invariably: Command-Alt-W. But it does not work, ever. I have latest MacOS Catalina. What is the answer to close all windows when I leave the computer open, so I don't have to wade through them all when I start up again from sleep?

Answer (score 0):

There's no command to close all windows of all apps. It would leave all the apps running anyway, just windowless.  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  is to close all windows of the current frontmost app.

The only time you get to choose whether all apps should quit is at logout, reboot or shutdown. Sleep is intended to be a temporary halt, so you can return to where you left off.